# Converting XML to JSON skipping root element

Tags: java, xml, json

I have to convert xml to JSON.I have implemented in below way

```
import net.sf.json.JSON;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer

XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
//xmlSerializer.setForceTopLevelObject(true);
//Above line is comented since i want to skip xml root element
JSON json = xmlSerializer.read(inputXml);
outJSON = json.toString(2);
```

**My input xml is**

```
<details>
    <name>
        <firstName>sir</firstName>
        <lastName>John</lastName>
        <midddleName>Nash</midddleName>
    </name>
    <address>24525 ross street</address>
</details>
```

**My output JSON is** which is coming fine skipping root the element

```
{
  "name":   {
    "firstName": "sir",
    "lastName": "John",
    "midddleName": "Nash"
  },
  "address": "24525 ross street"
}
```

But when i gave request as

```
<details>
    <name>
        <firstName>sir</firstName>
        <lastName>John</lastName>
        <midddleName>Nash</midddleName>
    </name>
</details>
```

My JSON response is

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "sir",
    "lastName": "John",
    "midddleName": "Nash"
  }
]
```

But i need response as

```
{
  "name":   {
    "firstName": "sir",
    "lastName": "John",
    "midddleName": "Nash"
  }
}
```

Please suggest me even if there any other API to provide this functionality

Comment: what is `XMLSerializer`?